# Uso de la expresión "así como que"

Tags: vocabulario

> cuando Wilfredo recibió el mensaje de su amigo Ramón, se vió así como que triste.  Dijo a su hermana que no podía ir con ellos a la fiesta.

Me gustaría saber si la expresión **así como que** es similar a la expresión **osea**. Gracias

Comment: To me, it sounds like "as if...".  Or more like, "Like...".  Like it sounds like it could be a dog that eats scooby snacks.

Comment: Like, ... you know?  Like, an expression or something like that.